# 'Component' is not defined no-undef Search for the keywords to learn more about each error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import './App.css';

import UserInput from './USerInput/UserInput';
import UserOutput from './UserOutput/UserOutput';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>Somekind of text </p>
        <userInput />
         <userOutput />
      </div>


    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

**UserInput.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

const userInput = () => {

return <input type="text" />
};

export default userInput;
```

**Output.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

const userOutput = () => {

return <input type="text" />
};

export default userOutput;
```

**Error is in * USerOutput.js  * could not be properly linked with src as it dims code line in VSCode too and the below component error**

```
./src/App.js
  Line 10:19:  'Component' is not defined  no-undef
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

*'Component' is not defined  no-undef  Search for the keywords to learn more about each error and previously *
this 
** Module not found: Can't resolve './App.css' in 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Reactjs\exercise\src\User Output'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the line of `class App extends Component` in **App.js** you need to import `Component` also.

Just like the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Failed to compile
./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './USerInput' in 'C:\Users\hp\Desktop\React JS\excercise\src'

Answer (score -2):

import React, { Component } from 'react';

import this package in top. And I hope it'll work

Comment: what is different from the other answers?